# Unauthorized client error with Google API using a service account to impersonate a connected email

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-oauth

I have been using the Google api client to access my companies' analytics data for the last 3 months using the method below, and it worked fine.

I then had to repeat the process with a different analytics account and I cannot get anything other than `{ "error" : "unauthorized_client", "error_description" : "Unauthorized client or scope in request." }`

The account is set up on console.developers.google.com under the account I want to impersonate, and the details/.p12 key are copied correctly.

I am not on a google apps domain, so no delegation is needed. I cannot understand why one service account/impersonation works fine, but I cannot recreate for any other analytics account.

Here is what I am using:

```
function __construct () 
{
    parent::__construct();

    // accessed via google developer console
    $client_email = '****.gserviceaccount.com';
    $private_key = file_get_contents(__DIR__ .'/cm-suite.p12');
    $scopes = array(\Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
    $user_to_impersonate = '****EMAIL***';

    $credentials = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $client_email,
        $scopes,
        $private_key,
        'notasecret',                                 
        'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer', 
        $user_to_impersonate
    );


    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);

    if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) 
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();

    // set reference for instance methods
    $this->client = &$client;
}
```

The accounts are added correctly in Analytics, and all the secure details are correct (if I am not trying to use a sub account, the service account connects correctly).

This problem is programming language agnostic I believe as my example worked before using a different account - so must be a configuration issue, or something I have missed settings-wise.

I cannot understand why it works for one google account, and not another.